# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object in trigger

Tags: trigger

```
trigger MassUploadChampionResponsible on Mass_Upload__c (after insert) {

Set<Id> msUploadContList = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id, User>  userMap;
List<Mass_Upload__c> msUpChmpionResponsibleList = new List<Mass_Upload__c>(); 
Id contactPerson;

for(Mass_Upload__c m:Trigger.new){  
    if(m.Contact_Person__c !=null){
        msUploadContList.add(m.Contact_Person__c);
        System.debug('#####msUploadContList'+msUploadContList);
    }
   }
   if(msUploadContList.size() > 0){
       userMap = new Map<Id,User>([ SELECT Id, IsActive,Champion_Responsible__c FROM User WHERE Id IN : msUploadContList ]);
       System.debug('#####userMap'+userMap);
   }

   for(Mass_Upload__c m:Trigger.new){ 
   contactPerson=m.Contact_Person__c; 
       if(Trigger.isInsert){
              Mass_Upload__c msup=new    Mass_Upload__c();
                  msup.Champion_Responsibles__c=userMap.get(m.Contact_Person__c).Champion_Responsible__c;
                   msUpChmpionResponsibleList.add(msup);
                   System.debug('#####msUpChmpionResponsibleList'+msUpChmpionResponsibleList);
       }       
   }

   if(msUpChmpionResponsibleList.size() > 0){
     insert msUpChmpionResponsibleList;    
   }

}
```

what is wrong in this code? Thanks!

Comment: tips: 1) - maps should always be initialized and 2) using `containsKey()` before using `get()` makes code more robust

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be on `m.Contact_Person__c` not existing in `userMap` Did it give you a line number?

Comment: yes, and usermap is not always initialized

Comment: Adding to Phil's comment, please add a null check before this line , msup.Champion_Responsibles__c=userMap.get(m.Contact_Person__c).Champion_Responsible__c;  This only seems to be the problem area. If (userMap.get(m.Contact_Person__c)!=null) , then look for userMap.get(m.Contact_Person__c).Champion_Responsible__c;